How do I fix broken pip installation
I'm not sure what has happened to my Ubuntu server. I just migrated from an old Ununtu 20.04 to 24.04, and most things seem to now by working all right.
However, if I run pip I get:
svend@localhost:~$ pip
-bash: /home/svend/.local/bin/pip: cannot execute: required file not found

If I run python -m pip it works all right:
svend@localhost:~$ python -m pip --version
pip 24.0 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.12)

I think the files in .local are actually from my old server, when I migrated everything in my home directory, and it might be the wrong version:
svend@localhost:~$ cat .local/bin/pip
#!/usr/bin/python3.10
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())

It seems that if I change the #! in the top of the script to #!/usr/bin/python3.12, it works again, but... that seems a bit hacky? Is there a better way of having these regenerated? I've tried: sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip, but that didn't seem to do it.
Edit: More info based on comments
If I run which -a pip I get:
svend@localhost:~$ which -a pip
/home/svend/.local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
/bin/pip

If I try to just run pip uninstall pip I get the This environment is externally managed warning. I presume I haven't overwritten that warning to install pip? So overriding it with --break-system-packages would presumably be risky if it could break the system python?
I tried renaming the pip, pip3 and virtualenv in .local/share to oldX, but for some reason it's still trying to run the one in .local:
svend@localhost:~$ mv .local/bin/pip .local/bin/oldpip
svend@localhost:~$ mv .local/bin/pip3 .local/bin/oldpip3
svend@localhost:~$ mv .local/bin/virtualenv .local/bin/oldvirtualenv
svend@localhost:~$ pip
-bash: /home/svend/.local/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Correction After deleting/moving them I just needed to start a new session, and that did indeed fix the issue. So thank you for that suggestion :D
The only thing in .local/share is an empty directory called virtualenv... I think I might have accidentally deleted everything in there yesterday, when I was also experimenting with removing .local/bin (I zipped up .local/bin and then deleted the entire .local and only realised my mistake when I unzipped the archive and it only contained the .local/bin and not .local/share... :/ I should note that this was after I noticed the broken commands)

Have you tried just pip uninstall pip and then  sudo apt install pip? Just an idea.

If I were you I would delete the file /home/svend/.local/bin/pip, it is probably not needed (and should be easy to recreate if needed), but of course I do not have all the details. Typically I do not know why one would want to have pip at this location, that does not seem useful to me. -- All in all you can probably delete everything that is not created by the apt package manager.

which -a pip will list you all the pip executables in PATH. The one in ~/.local/bin looks like a remainder of a local pip installation using an older Python version, which start breaking stuff now as you already found out; I would check for other packages in the user site as well (most probably in ~/.local/share/pythonX.Y directories), whether those are still needed and can be cleaned up.

In Bash hash -r pip will tell Bash to forget where pip used to be and look for it again.

We can't know what created .local/bin/pip so it's hard to predict the consequences of making changes to it. I would not worry about the "hack" to edit this file; it's in your home directory, so whatever put it there probably wanted you to take ownership.

which is hard to eradicate and actually happens to work on Ubuntu, but the correct POSIX command is command -v
